# What is this weird interference/strange radio station?

Tags: software-defined-radio, hf, signal-identification, swl

When I was checking if my antenna is working properly using websdr.org, I came upon this: On 4480 kHz, there are some strange noises. You can also see it in the waterfall [here](http://websdr.k3fef.com:8901/). Is it just some interference, or is it some old abandoned mysterious creepy russian radio station like UVB-76 (the buzzer)? The signal covers a lot, roughly 4447-4503 kHz, so it makes it even more mysterious. I don't know what is it's name if it's a radio station, so I can't do research on it. But, all I know is that my poor EFHW antenna can't receive it. I'm looking for what is it's name, if it has one, and what does it do. Hopefully it's not a creepy radio station, because I have dealt with enough of those radio stations in my life. There hasn't been information on it (yet) on [priyom.org](https://priyom.org).

UPDATE:
Now, there is another smaller one at the WTWW station.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, from my humble experience as engineer, there's a rule of thumb: unless proven otherwise, it's practically never "the other thing" that's broken, it's either one's own understanding or one's own usage or measurement. This has been a rather painful experience to make, but remembering it has helped me fix my mistakes ever since :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oceanographic radar, aka [CODAR](https://www.sigidwiki.com/wiki/CODAR). It's used to measure ocean currents, wave heights and frequencies by the way the waves reflect RF.